# MS-SQL-08: Is it possible to create a view that depends on a function before the function has been created?

Tags: sql-server, dependencies

Using MS-SQL-08:

Is it possible to somehow temporarily disable dependency checking, so that I can create a view that uses a function that does not exist (has not yet been created) at the time of creating the view.  [then create the required function, and finally re-enable dependency checking]

So, lets say I have view V, which uses function F, the order I would like to be able to achieve is

turn off dependency checks
1. create V
2. create F
turn dependency checks back on

Thanks.

Comment: This just sounds silly.   Create the function first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called `deferred name resolution` and while you can create a proc that select from a table if the table does not exists you cannot do that with a view that uses a function

example of the proc

```
create procedure prTest
as select * from MyTestTable
go

create table MyTestTable(id int)
go

exec prTest
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible as SQL Server needs to evaluate the view on creation to derive the types for the columns.

Just create a dummy function, or if you know there's going to be function which returns a specific type replace it with something like `SELECT CAST(NULL AS tinyiny) as MyFuncPlaceholder`

Answer (score 0):

A possible work-around would be to create a dummy (or placeholder) function, create the view using it *without* schema-binding, then later replace the function with the desired one.

This might not work--I vaguely recall a situation where we altered a table within a view, and then the view would not work until it was "reset" (which could be as simple as issuing an ALTER VIEW statement with the exact same definition). Do a lot of testing, and be prepared to write awkward code.

Comment: sp_refreshview would probably have to be called

Comment: Sounds right. I haven't had much to do with views in recent times.